# Problemas Toast Alertas Android

Tags: android-studio, alertdialog, webview-android, android-toast

Tengo estos códigos en mi MainActivity.java pretendo mostrar una alerta de tipo toast con una duración de un segundo y que si le doy 50 veces y dejo de pulsar no siga apareciendo, que se cancelen los anteriores.Que no aparezcan cuando cambio a otra aplicación,cuando la dejo en segundo plano o la cierro. pero a pesar de que estos códigos funcionan. Cuando abro otra aplicación los métodos ondestroy y onstop y especialmente el toast.cancel me cierra la actividad y no me deja regresar con el backbutton alguien sabe como solucionarlo hay alguna alternativa a toast.cancel que no me de estos problemas.

```
 final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El mensaje dura 1 segundo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {



            @Override
            public void run() {

                    toast.cancel();


            }
        }, 900);




@Override
protected void onStop () {
    super.onStop();

    toast.cancel();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    toast.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Prueba con System.exit(0); en vez de toast.cancel();

Answer (score 1):

Debes definir la variable `toast` a nivel global de tu clase

```
private Toast toast;
```

y llamar el método de la instancia de Toast:

```
 toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El mensaje dura 1 segundo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {     

            @Override
            public void run() {

                    toast.cancel();

            }
        }, 900);
```

Recuerda que si quieres cancelar el Toast al mandar tu aplicación a segundo plano (background), debes usar el método `onPause()`

```
@Override
protected void onPause () {
    super.onPause();
   //Cancela!
    toast.cancel();
}
```

Comment: esto sigue sin funcionar y he hecho exactamente lo mismo...

Comment: @MBS.corp estas creando solo una instancia del Toast o son varias?

Comment: Una por método en función de si se simple determinada condición, se mostraría por ejemplo si le acepto saldría Toast aceptado y si deniego Toast alerta que diga no has aceptado ...